# ClassNotFoundException when using spark intelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, jvm

I'm tying to run this example in IntelliJ

```
  import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
  import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
  object LAspark {
      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val logFile = "/Users/H/Desktop/sparktest.txt" 
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple 
 Application").setMaster("local[*]")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
        val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
        val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
        println("Lines with a: %s, Lines with b: %s".format(numAs, numBs))
     }
 }
```

and here is error that I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LAspark
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:123)
```

My build.sbt is like this:

```
name := "fridaytest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

In Global Libraries I used scala-sdk-2.11.8. I spent hours on this and still couldn't figure out what the problem was. Could someone please help? Many thanks.

Comment: can you update the post with directory tree for the class?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I looked at the project directory and realized that my code was under folder scala2.12, as that was the sdk I was using before switched to 2.11.... I moved the code to folder 2.11 and it worked..

Comment: great to hear that. you can post your answer to this question below. :)

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. After seeing Ramesh Maharjan's comment I looked at the project directory and realized that my code was under folder scala2.12, as that was the sdk I was using before switching to 2.11. The IDE'd generate different folders as you change the version of JDK you use in 'project structure'. I moved the code to folder 2.11 and it worked. As it turns out folder matters..